# Why input events aren't fired when using Jquery mask plugin with Backbone.js?

Tags: jquery, events, backbone.js, input, jquery-mask

Let's say i have the following HTML template :

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">                                                          
            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email">                                                        
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">                                                          
            <input class="form-control tel" type="text" id="phone" name="phone">                                                        
        </div>
        // rest of the ui
    </form>
</script>

<script>
    // Backbone View 
    SomeForm = Backbone.View.extend({
        template:$('#template').html(),
        events:{
            'input .tel':'telChanged'   
        },
        telChanged:function(e){
            var value = this.$('.tel').val();
            console.log('tel changed, value = ',value);
        },
        render:function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            // some example that uses 
            this.$('.tel').mask('9-999-999-999');
            return this;
        }
    });

    var view = new SomeForm();
    $('#app').html(view.render().$el);


</script>
```

Now whenever the user type in the `.tel` input the `telChanged` method is not triggered and nothing is printed to the console!

Can anyone tell us what is causing this and thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems to work as expected http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/dxzpqzfe/1/

Comment: @nikoshr Where is the input field ?

Comment: jQuery.mask was not loaded in my Fiddle on Chrome. Try http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/dxzpqzfe/2/

Comment: @nikoshr  Thanks for your comment.
It is funny, it is working as expected but i'm talking about [jquery.maskedinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) and you are talking about [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin)